# iOS, CPU keeps increasing upon playing new song

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avplayer

I am using AVPlayer to play music via Streaming URLs. Upon playing the first song the CPU is at about 3-4%, but each time a new song gets played the CPU will jump up and seem to get stacked on itself. Why is this happening? This is the code I am using to play music.

```
- (void)updateTime {

    UIImage *pauseButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Pause"];
    float duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentItem.duration);
    float current = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentTime);

    self.durationProgressView.progress = (current/duration);
    if (self.durationProgressView.progress == 0)
    {
        [self.playPauseButton setBackgroundImage:pauseButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}

-(void)playCurrentArtist:(NSDictionary *)currentArtist
{
    NSString *streamString = [currentArtist objectForKey:@"stream_url"];
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?client_id=%@", streamString,CLIENT_ID];
    NSURL *URLFromString = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    self.player = nil;
    AVPlayer *playerWithURL = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:URLFromString];
    self.player = playerWithURL;
    [self.player play];
    self.durationProgressView.hidden = NO;
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemDidFinishPlaying:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:[self.player currentItem]];
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.05 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)itemDidFinishPlaying:(NSNotification *) notification {
    //if there are no tracks in queue
    if (![self.hostQueue count]) {
        NSLog(@"nothing in queue upon song finishing");
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:[self.player currentItem]];
        [self.hostCurrentArtist removeAllObjects];
        [self setCurrentArtistFromCurrentArtist:self.hostCurrentArtist];
        NSArray *argsCurrentArray = @[self.hostCurrentArtist];
        [self.socket emit:kCurrentArtistChange args:argsCurrentArray];
    }
    else {
        [self playNextSongInQueue];
        [self setCurrentArtistFromCurrentArtist:self.hostCurrentArtist];
    };
}

-(void)playNextSongInQueue
{
    if ([self.hostQueue count]) {
        [self.audioPlayer stop];
        [self.timer invalidate];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:[self.player currentItem]];
        UIImage *pausedButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Pause"];
        //Rearange tracks and current songs and emit them to the sever.
        NSDictionary *currentTrack = [self.hostQueue objectAtIndex:0];
        self.hostCurrentArtist = [currentTrack mutableCopy];
        [self.hostQueue removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [self.tableView reloadData];

        [self playCurrentArtist:self.hostCurrentArtist];

        [self.playPauseButton setBackgroundImage:pausedButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.audioPlayer.delegate = self;
        self.durationProgressView.hidden = NO;
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.5 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

        NSArray *argsWithQueue = @[self.hostQueue];
        NSArray *arrayWithTrack = @[currentTrack];
        [self setCurrentArtistFromCurrentArtist:self.hostCurrentArtist];

    }
}
```

Comment: Use [AVPlayer playerWithURL:URLFromString] instead of initWithURL

Comment: thanks, but now it goes up by about 1.5% per skip/next song. @user523234

Comment: What is self.audioPlayer?

Comment: I got rid of that, it was unnecessary, left over from when I was trying to use AudioPlayer instead of AVPlayer still having issues though.  @user523234